# php application made using codeigniter framework links are not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, ubuntu-server

I set up a ubuntu server in a virtual pc. and I put my php application that was created using codeigniter framework to /var/www/sdbl folder.

now i can view the index page of my application. but all links are broken.

I put these codes in to .htaccess file and it is in /var/www/sdbl folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

the same application is working well on this link
http://3linksit.com/sdbl/

can some one give me some help with this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What link are you going to that isn't working? What does "not working" mean? Server error/404/nothing happens?

Comment: i just found that... this link is working but i want to remove index.php thing. 
http://localhost/sdbl/index.php/new_user
http://localhost/sdbl/new_user this link is going to 404 error page

Comment: What are you using to create the links? The anchor function native to codeigniter?

Comment: @Cameeob2003 - didn't get you

Comment: @Yasitha Im assuming that you are either hardcoding the links via `<a href="<?php echo base_url(''your/url'); ?>">Your Link</a>` or you are using `<?php anchor('your/link/info'); ?>`. Would that be a correct assumption? Either way did you ensure that you set `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` to `$config['index_page'] = '';` in config.php?

Comment: Is that the same .htaccess as you are using on the working version of the site? If the server environments are different it could mean you need to make a slight change to your `htaccess` to get it working. A common solution is to add a questionmark `?` after the index.php and before the `/`

Comment: @Cameeob2003 - I hand coded the links. didn't use anchor functions. and also i did $config['index_page'] = '' ;

Answer (score 0):

If i have got your question right you want to make your links working & remove 'index.php' from URL.Follow following steps & let me know if that solves your issue.

1) Remove **'index.php'** from **config.php** which is located in **config** directory 
make it look like this `$config['index_page'] = '';`

2) Add this to .htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

If you have any doubts or issues let me know.Hope it helps.

Best Regards,
Zeeshan.

Comment: Still having the problem
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root    root     156 2013-11-10 05:04 .htaccess
my htaccess file permision is like this. is it ok?